# vb6 how to find string and remove unwanted by index

Tags: vb6

please look at the code i have below and the image label1 = 2 represents index of winsock
trying to count the index of winsock with the list1 /index values and if non are matched with label2 then remove item

[image]

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim demopacket() As String
Dim X As Integer


For X = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

demopacket() = Split(List1.List(X), "/")
Dim num As Integer
num = num + 1
Debug.Print num

If num = Label1.Caption Then
'Exit For
End If

If Label1.Caption = demopacket(2) Then
Else

List1.RemoveItem X
lstOnline.RemoveItem X

'RemoveUser List1.List(X)
'RemoveUserFromRoom List1.List(X)
Call RemoveUser(demopacket(0))
Call RemoveUserFromRoom(demopacket(0))
Call RoomCount(demopacket(1), False)

End If
'Debug.Print demopacket(0)
'demopacket(0)  username
'demopacket(1) roomname
'demopacket(2) index

Next
```

still removes index users that exist

so again
label1.caption = 2

xxx2x/room1/4 **Remove**
jas8du2/room1/1
mosdjas/room2/2
jaosjdiasjd/room1/5 **Remove**
jasidjas92m/room1/8 **Remove**

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to remove everything except those lines containing a "2".  If this is the case, then your code works for me.

Comment: correct example label1.caption has value of 2 so it is index 2  so check list1 for index 1 if it exist, then index2 and so on. if they exist keep them or else remove them

Comment: so compare all the index from label1.caption = 2 with jas8du2/room1/1  <<this end value only on each line in list1

Comment: example label1.caption = 2   remember label1 has passed index 1 and become 2 and this digit will go up.   so compare this value with the value in list1 and remove any unwanted items that do not match any index    so we keep   jas8du2/room1/1 because label1 has passed index1 and now check the next   mosdjas/room2/2 keep this also label1 passed 2 or on 2